# ¿Es posible hacer la media de todos los valores de una coleccion relacionada con ObjectId?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo estas dos colecciones:

```
  var wineSchema = new Schema({
  name:         { type: String }, //nombre del vino
  code:       { type:String},
  type:         {
                    type: String,
                    enum: ['Tinto','Rosado','Blanco']
                },
  winery:       { type: String }, //Viñedo
  grape_type:   { type: String }, //tipo de uva
  year:         { type: Number }, // añada
  alcohol:      { type: Number },  //grados de alcohol
  rates:  [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Puntuacion" }],
  comentarios:  [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Comentario" }],
});

var puntuacion = new Schema({
  usuario   : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Usuario" },
  usuName   : {type: String},
  vineName  : { type: String},
  puntuacion    : { type: Number}
});
```

Es posible hacer la media de todas las puntuaciones de puntuacion.puntuacion de cada vino. La idea es hacer primero un populate par que me muestre todos los vinos con sus respectivas puntuaciones y después de todas estas hacer una media de puntuacion.puntuacion con aggregate..

No se si es posible hacerlo.. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Me falta experiencia en Node para contestar con seguridad. Entiendo que no debería ser difícil calcular la media "a mano" en tu programa con wineSchema.puntuación. También entiendo que Mongo te daría la media de cada vino (por nombre) con `db.puntuacion.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$wineName", average : {$avg : "$puntuacion"}}])`, así que usando _populate_ algo como `wine.find().populate("rates").exec(function (err, wines) {XYZ});` donde XYZ calcule wineSchema.average podría valer... Pero como digo me falta experiencia con Node y populate(), así que no me hagas mucho caso...

Answer (score 2):

El caso es que @Diego está en lo correcto.

Un par de apuntes:

- No es generalmente buena práctica hacer un array de puntuaciones en el modelo de vino, porque termina eventualmente uno sin espacio (recuerda que un documento no puede exceder el tamaño determinado por su `BSON`), y esto no es bueno si el vino va a tener… ¿20.000 puntuaciones? Aparte de todo lo anterior, se hará más fácil hacer un `aggregator` desde un modelo y no a nivel de documentos. En ese caso en el modelo de puntuación es donde se hace la referencia al vino. Caso diferente al de los comentarios, donde por norma general no son muchos, pero si lo son, la misma cosa.
- Lo normal, programar en un solo idioma, eso de combinar inglés con español a veces es un tanto raro. Además, usar `camelCase` en lugar de `snake_case`, ya que bueno… ¡es Javascript!

Ahora si, empecemos:

En el archivo del modelo `Wine`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
,     Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

let wineSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: [ 'Tinto', 'Rosado', 'Blanco' ],
        required: true
    },
    winery: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    grapeType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    alcohol: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model('Wine', wineSchema);
```

En el archivo del modelo `Rate`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
,     Schema   = mongoose.Schema
,     ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

let rateSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    },
    wine: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Wine",
        required: true
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

rateSchema.statics.avg = function(wineId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                wine: new ObjectId(wineId)
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$wine',
                rate: {
                    $avg: '$rate'
                }
            }
        }], (error, results) => {
            if(error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(results);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rate', rateSchema);
```